# Чем опасно самоприсваивание в своем реализуемом классе?

Tags: c++, указатели

> Ниже пояснено что может появится висячий указатель, но я не совсем понимаю как это возможно

```
// перегруженная операция =; предотвращает самоприсваивание
const String fiString::operator=( const String &right )
{
    cout <<"operator= called" << endl;
    if ( &right != this ) // предотвратить самоприсваивание
    {
        delete [] sPtr; // предотвращает утечку памяти
        length = right.length; // новая длина строки
        setString( right.sPtr ); // вызвать вспомогательную функцию
    } // конец if
    else
        cout << "Attempted assignment of a String to itself" << endl;

    return *this; // разрешает каскадное присваивание
} // конец функции operator=
```

Comment: Вообще-то если оператор присвоения вынужден проверять, не присваивает ли он объект самому себе (не для эффективности, а иначе ошибка будет) - это плохо написанный оператор...

Comment: А как правильнее будет?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Потому что это означает лишнее место для ошибки :) А в случае какого-нибудь переопределенного оператора & - и просто явную ошибку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить код без

```
49 if ( &right != this ) // предотвратить самоприсваивание
```

Что будет? Сначала удалится `sPtr`, а потом `setString( right.sPtr );` где `right.sPtr=this.sPtr` уже удалено, то есть никакого string нету. Ясно, что информация потеряется.

Comment: А что будет если сначала удалить sPtr, а потом setString приведет к исключению? Лучше б другую книжку найти

Answer (score 3):

В ответ на "как правильнее". Есть разные варианты. Вот, в качестве примера оператор присваивания строки `String` другой такой строке... явно ведь есть копирующий конструктор? Допишем еще функцию обмена "внутренностями" `swap` - т.е. если класс примерно

```
class String { 
    int length; 
    char * sPtr;
    ...
```

то это что-то вроде (для простоты не стал использовать стандартную `::swap`:

```
void String::swap(String& s)
{
    int tmp = length; length = s.length; s.length = tmp;
    char * ptr = sPtr; sPtr = s.sPtr; s.sPtr = ptr;
}
```

тогда вот такой оператор присваивания

```
String& operator=(const String& src)
{
    String tmp(src);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

выполнит присваивание, не нуждаясь в проверке присваивания самому себе. Ее (эту проверку) можно добавить - для эффективности, но не для предотвращения ошибок.

Можно копирование сделать неявным:

```
String& operator=(const String src)
{
    swap(src);
    return *this;
}
```

Тут проверку присваивания себе просто некуда воткнуть... :)